# $f(0,p)$ for $f(x,p) = \int \frac{\sin(2x)}{x} C_i(x+p) dx$

Tags: integration

How do i find $f(0,p)$ for $$f(x,p) = \int \frac{\sin(2x)}{x} C_i(x+p) dx$$

$C_i(x)$ is [Cosine Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html). Obviously, if I could solve the integral, I would have substituted $x$ with $0$. But I don't know how to solve it. I wonder if there is a general technique for finding the value of this function at a particular point, even if I can't solve it generally for all values of $x$. Ignore the constant of integration (the usual +C term for indefinite integrals)

Comment: If you write it as $\int_0^x\frac{\sin2t}t\operatorname{Ci}(t+p)\,dt$ then at $x=0$ it equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

What I would probably try is to expand the cosine integral around $x=0$
$$\text{Ci}(x+p)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n!\,p^n}x^n$$  and face the integrals
$$I_n(x)=\int x^{n-1} \sin (2 x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2} i x^n (E_{1-n}(-2 i x)-E_{1-n}(2 i x))$$ that is to say
$$I_n(0)=-2^{-n} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right) \Gamma (n,0)$$ So,
$$I_{2n}(0)=0 \qquad \text{and}\qquad I_{2n+1}(0)=(-1)^{n+1}2^{-(2 n+1)} \Gamma (2 n+1,0)$$

This would give
$$f(0,p)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{ \Gamma (2 n+1,0)}{(2p)^{2n+1} \,(2n+1)! } a_{2n+1}$$

Now
$$a_{2n+1}=P_{n}\, \cos(p)+Q_{n} \,\sin(p)$$ and the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & -p^2 +2\\
 2 & p^4-12 p^2+24 \\
 3 & -p^6+30 p^4-360 p^2+720 \\
 4 & p^8-56 p^6+1680 p^4-20160 p^2+40320 \\
 5 & -p^{10}+90 p^8-5040 p^6+151200 p^4-1814400 p^2+3628800 \\
 6 & p^{12}-132 p^{10}+11880 p^8-665280 p^6+19958400 p^4-239500800 p^2+479001600
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & Q_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 p \\
 2 & -4 p^3+24p \\
 3 & 6 p^5-120 p^3+720 p \\
 4 & -8 p^7+336 p^5-6720 p^3+40320 p \\
 5 & 10 p^9-720 p^7+30240 p^5-604800 p^3+3628800 p \\
 6 & -12 p^{11}+1320 p^9-95040 p^7+3991680 p^5-79833600 p^3+479001600 p
\end{array}
\right)$$ where interesting patterns appear.